# Hiding table cells with media query causing unexpected results in Chrome, but fine if you reload page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

http://staging.isaidicanshout.com/millersrest/

Hello, in the WIP example above, when sizing down below 1024, this site should switch to a single column view, by hiding two of the table-cells and resizing the width of the page. However, in Chrome it hides the cells, but leaves the remaining cell at its original width. Reloading the page at the new size gives the correct appearance. Any idea why this would not update correctly in Chrome?

Safari seems to work fine. Firefox is an entirely other story, but I will look into that separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have a `position:relative;` for `#leftcol` and `#rightcol`. When you have a media screen for 1024px, make sure you remove this attribute and then it will work as a one column display. See in the picture below how it is working, but most importantly that `position:relative` is unchecked
[image]